# MuiTabPanl-Root Padding remove using CSS or Mui Styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to override the MUI Tab Panel Padding. I override the .MuiTabPanel-Root Class globally and inline style. But, the Tab Panel is not override. Screenshot and Code Below attached.

I want to remove the padding from the MuiTabPanel-Root class padding.

When I applied the padding as 0px in "MuiTabPanel-Root" class is not working.
But, When I remove the padding from this class .css-13xfq8m-MuiTabPanel-root Tab panel padding was removed. I don't know how to override the "TabPanel-root padding" using react js

CSS Global :

```
.MuiTabPanel-root{
padding: 0px;
}
```

CSS Inline :

```
<TabPanel value="1" classes={{
        "& .MuiTabPanel-root": {
          padding: "0px",
        },
      }}>
```

Full Code Tab Component :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import TabContext from '@mui/lab/TabContext';
import TabList from '@mui/lab/TabList';
import TabPanel from '@mui/lab/TabPanel';
import HistoryTable from '../HistoryTable/HistoryTable';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import SampleTable from './SampleTable';
import './TradeTab.css';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { orange, pink, green } from "@material-ui/core/colors";


export default function SampleTabControl() {
  const theme = createTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiTabs: {
        indicator: {
          backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
      },
      MuiTab: {
        root: {
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: pink[100],
            color: pink[700]
          },
          ".MuiTabPanel-root":{
            padding:0
          }
        },
        selected: {
          backgroundColor: orange[100],
          color: orange[700],
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            color: green[700]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('1');

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%', typography: 'body1'}}>
      <TabContext value={value}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
          <TabList onChange={handleChange} aria-label="lab API tabs example">
            <Tab label="Item One" value="1" style={{color: "white", fontWeight:"500"}}
            sx={{backgroundColor: value=="1" ? "blue" : "lightgrey" }}/>
            <Tab label="Item Two" value="2" style={{color: "white", fontWeight:"500", marginLeft:'10px'}}
            sx={{backgroundColor: value=="2" ? "blue" : "lightgrey"}}/>
            <Button variant='outlined' style={{marginLeft:'100px', size:'small', height:'30px', marginTop:"10px"}}>1X</Button>
          </TabList>
        </Box>
        <TabPanel value="1" classes={{
        "& .MuiTabPanel-root": {
          padding: "0px",
        },
      }}>
          <SampleTable/>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value="2">Item Two</TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value="3">Item Three</TabPanel>
      </TabContext>
    </Box>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Full Code Table :

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import MaterialReactTable from 'material-react-table';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

//nested data is ok, see accessorKeys in ColumnDef below
const data = [
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
    },
    address: '261 Erdman Ford',
    city: 'East Daphne',
    state: 'Kentucky',
  },
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'Jane',
      lastName: 'Doe',
    },
    address: '769 Dominic Grove',
    city: 'Columbus',
    state: 'Ohio',
  },
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'Joe',
      lastName: 'Doe',
    },
    address: '566 Brakus Inlet',
    city: 'South Linda',
    state: 'West Virginia',
  },
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'Kevin',
      lastName: 'Vandy',
    },
    address: '722 Emie Stream',
    city: 'Lincoln',
    state: 'Nebraska',
  },
  {
    name: {
      firstName: 'Joshua',
      lastName: 'Rolluffs',
    },
    address: '32188 Larkin Turnpike',
    city: 'Charleston',
    state: 'South Carolina',
  },
];

const SampleTable = () => {
  //should be memoized or stable
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        accessorKey: 'name.firstName', //access nested data with dot notation
        header: 'First Name',
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'name.lastName',
        header: 'Last Name',
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'address', //normal accessorKey
        header: 'Address',
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'city',
        header: 'City',
      },
      {
        accessorKey: 'state',
        header: 'State',
      },
    ],
    [],
  );

  return <MaterialReactTable columns={columns} data={data} style={{padding:'0px'}}/>;
};

export default SampleTable;
```

I try to remove the padding for "MuiTabPanel-root".

Expected Result :
Remove the padding from "MuiTabPanel-Root"

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in codesandbox or other similar websites. You probably be able to figure it out on your own if you inspect the `div` which is rendered by `TabPanel`.